# Can't figure out what this code does exactly

Tags: windows, batch-file, admin

I'm trying to deploy an application via sccm to windows 7 pcs (Around 300 pcs). the app is based on Java jre-7u55.
There is no problem with deployment or the app. Deployment works , yet the problem is for nonadmin and admin users the app is promoting windows UAC. and application will only allow to run  for Admin users not for normal users thought they provide their right credentials. (App referred here is a short cut created by bat file that will load java binaries,program stuff)

This is the bat file..

```
@echo off 
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------


:install
set GAS_BIN=%~dp0
cd %GAS_BIN%
cd ..
set GAS_HOME=%cd%

cd "%GAS_HOME%"
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128M
set CLASSPATH=bin/*
set JAVA_HOME=C:/Java/jre1.7.0.55
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%PATH%
start "GAS STANDALONE" "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw" %JAVA_OPTS% -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" com.airbus.agsm.core.launcher.ServerMain

:done
endlocal
```

**What my concern about is below code (I know this is the thing that is responsible for UAC)** **uac code**

```
   @echo off 
    setlocal
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    :: BatchGotAdmin
    :-------------------------------------
    REM  --> Check for permissions
    >nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

    REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
    if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
        echo Requesting administrative privileges...
        goto UACPrompt
    ) else ( goto gotAdmin )

    :UACPrompt
        echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
        echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

        "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
        exit /B

    :gotAdmin
        if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
        pushd "%CD%"
        CD /D "%~dp0"
    :--------------------------------------
```

I have certain understanding about programming. Yet I want to make sure is this the part that forces  admin privileges to run/load the Java code..

OR **is it trying to do something else and failed and then request for admin privileges for running the app for non-admin users.**

I need to understand it correctly to go ahead with windows troubleshooting or any other , to make it work for non-admin users .

Please help to interpreter it correctly. (Three is less support from app creator as well as Im a system deployment guy not a programmer)

Comment: how exactly is this Java related?

Comment: :install
set GAS_BIN=%~dp0
cd %GAS_BIN%
cd ..
set GAS_HOME=%cd%

cd "%GAS_HOME%"
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128M
set CLASSPATH=bin/*
set JAVA_HOME=C:/Java/jre1.7.0.55
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%PATH%
start "GAS STANDALONE" "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw" %JAVA_OPTS% -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" com.airbus.agsm.core.launcher.ServerMain

:done
endlocal

Comment: its the latter part of the code

Comment: What is in the vbs script `getadmin.vbs`?

Comment: None of the code you are supplying is actually java. Some kind of shell-script from what I can tell.

Comment: @user879 since you're not running Java code (as Tobb pointed out) but are trying to set a path to Java ... how is this actually Java related?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ita in the batfile it self has echo command Redirect standard output to getadmin.vbs .. Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1

Comment: @Stultuske May be you are correct .. But can you help me to interpret what uac code does in bat file ? I need to make it work for none admin users.. I have not problem with java application it works.. Noly problem is nonadmin users are prompted with uac, but giving correct credintials will not allow them to go ahead and launch the application

Comment: do understand: this has nothing to do with Java, since you tag it as such, it will be read by people looking to help you solve a Java issue. Secondly, you don't show us any of the code that is run, and that might cause the problem

Comment: I removed java tag.. Im pretty new.. Sorry about that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )
```

This tries to run command `cacls`with `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system` as parameter. This command will succeed if the current user has privileges so the `%errorlevel%` will be 0, it will fail if current user has not enough privileges so the `%errorlevel%` will not be 0. If the command fails `:UACPrompt` subroutine is called.

```
:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B
```

Shell script is created. This shell script requests UAC higher level of privilege and then calls the bat script again but this time with higher level of privilege. Code executes the shell script and terminates with `exit /B` command.

The shell script calls the BAT code again, but since we have higher privileges now `:UACPrompt` is not executed and execution is "skipped" to `:gotAdmin`.

```
:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
```

Which deletes shell script and sets state which will enable the rest of the script to run normally.

**The code is trying to do something that requires admin privileges, if it fails it will request admin privileges from the user**